# How to use a macro to name an enum in C?

Tags: c, enums, macros

I have a library with hundreds of macros in the following format:

```
#define EVENT_A 0
#define EVENT_B 1
#define EVENT_C 2
...
```

However, I would like to streamline this process to easily change the "EVENT_" prefix.

I can nest the macros to make it nicer and allow for easy definition of multiple event sets:

```
#define DEFINE_EVENT(name,value)   EVENT_##name = value

DEFINE_EVENT(A, 0)
DEFINE_EVENT(B, 1)
DEFINE_EVENT(C, 2)
```

But I would also like to have the prefix `EVENT_` controlled by a macro to make it easier when playing with the stringified version of the event macros later.
Something like the following (which does not work)

```
#define EVENT_PREFIX               "EVENT_"
#define DEFINE_EVENT(name,value)   EVENT_PREFIX##name = value

DEFINE_EVENT(A, 0)
DEFINE_EVENT(B, 1)
DEFINE_EVENT(C, 2)
```

Is it possible to use the `EVENT_PREFIX` macro in the `DEFINE_EVENT` macro to help name the events?

---

As you cannot create macros with other macros, I am editing the question to utilize macros to name an enum. If I create an enum as follows:

```
#define DEFINE_EVENT(name, value)   EVENT_##name = value,
enum {
    #include "events.txt"
};
#undef DEFINE_EVENT
```

With the following `events.txt`:

```
DEFINE_EVENT(A,0)
DEFINE_EVENT(B,1)
DEFINE_EVENT(C,2)
```

Would it be possible to add a macro for the `EVENT_PREFIX`? Something like

```
#define EVENT_PREFIX     "EVENT_"
#define DEFINE_EVENT(name, value)   EVENT_PREFIX##name = value,
enum {
    #include "events.txt"
};
#undef DEFINE_EVENT
```

Comment: You can't create macros with other macros. There might be other creative solutions, but for that the exact use-case is needed.

Comment: What about using it to name an enum value? `#define DEFINE_EVENT(name,value) enum{  EVENT_PREFIX##name = value };`
This won't do what I want it to as is, but it's more the concept I'm curious about. Can I use the EVENT_PREFIX macro to name an enum value?

Comment: Yes, this is something you can do. The difference is that macros are processed by the pre-processor, and can't generate additional preprocessor directives. But the enum names are processed by the compiler after the preprocessor is done.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks Eugene! I've edited the initial question to delve into using macros to name an enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `##` opererator concatenates two tokens directly -- it does not matter if those tokens are themselves macros as no expansion will take place prior to the concatenation.  If you *want* to expand macros prior to concatenation, you'll need multiple macros to control that

```
#define CONCAT(A,B)                A##B
#define EXPAND_CONCAT(A,B)         CONCAT(A,B)
#define EVENT_PREFIX               EVENT_
#define DEFINE_EVENT(name,value)   EXPAND_CONCAT(EVENT_PREFIX, name) = value
```

Here the `CONCAT` macro just concatenates two tokens directly (using `##`).  The `EXPAND_CONCAT` macro will first expand any macros in its arguments, and then concatenate the results.

Also note that you don't want quotes around `EVENT_` as that will make it a string, not a name, and interfere with the concatenation

Comment: Gotta love the double CONCAT macros to expand it properly. Thanks for the explanation, Chris!

Answer (score 2):

Correct use of "X macros" would be like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// list of all postfix names and their corresponding values:
#define POSTFIX_LIST(X) \
  X(A,   0) \
  X(B,  42) \
  X(C, 666) \

typedef enum
{
  #define CREATE_EVENT_ENUM(postfix, val) EVENT_##postfix = val, 
  // run the above macro for every item in the list:
  POSTFIX_LIST(CREATE_EVENT_ENUM)
} event_t;

int main (void)
{
  printf("%d\n", EVENT_A);
  printf("%d\n", EVENT_B);
  printf("%d\n", EVENT_C);
}
```

If you wish a variable prefix then you'll have to do as in the answer by @Chris Dodd - expand the macros before `##` is applied. That's because `##` is evaluated by the pre-processor before any macro expansion inside the macro where it is found. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PREFIX EVENT_
#define POSTFIX_LIST(X) \
  X(A,   0) \
  X(B,  42) \
  X(C, 666) \

#define CONCAT(x,y) x ## y
#define EXPAND_CONCAT(x,y) CONCAT(x,y)

typedef enum
{
  #define CREATE_ENUM(postfix, val) EXPAND_CONCAT(PREFIX, postfix) = val,
  POSTFIX_LIST(CREATE_ENUM)
} event_t;

int main (void)
{
  printf("%d\n", EVENT_A);
  printf("%d\n", EVENT_B);
  printf("%d\n", EVENT_C);
}
```

From there on, "stringification" can be done similarly, as `#` works the same as `##` in terms of expansion. Although in "stringification" we can take advantage of string literals getting automatically concatenated by the pre-processor in a later pre-processor translation phase, so no need to use `##` for that:

```
#define STR_CONCAT(x,y) #x #y  // this becomes "EVENT_" "A"  etc then -> "EVENT_A"
#define EXPAND_STR_CONCAT(x, y) STR_CONCAT(x,y)

const char str_list[][100] =
{
  #define STRINGIFY(postfix, val) EXPAND_STR_CONCAT(PREFIX, postfix),
  POSTFIX_LIST(STRINGIFY)
};
for(size_t i=0; i<3; i++)
  puts(str_list[i]);
```

Comment: (If even vals are always 0,1,2... then this can be simplified some. This example is for non-adjacent enum vals, which is somewhat more complex to work with.)

Comment: This makes sense. I appreciate the thorough explanation!